# NoClassDefFound org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, microprofile, eclipse-microprofile-config

I have a small rest client project using **microprofile 3.3** and i want to deploy it on a raw **wildfly 21.0.1.FINAL** using the standalone-microprofile.xml.

This project has activated security with jwt and calls another rest-service via @RegisterRestClient-Interface.

**I have the problem that the authorization header is not transferred to the following intern rest-call.**

In my research i found out that in DefaultClientHeadersFactoryImpl.config() an error occurs that the **class ConfigProvider is not found**. I thought that using the microprofile-dependency in pom and standalone-microprofile.xml in wildfly add all dependencies for microprofile automatically. Also when i add microprofile-config-api additionally and not provided i get this error.

Does anyone know this problem and how to fix it?

If you need additional information: Just ask ;-)

My only dependency in the pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
        <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am launching wildfly with following parameter:

```
--server-config=standalone-microprofile.xml
```

The projects are available at [Github](https://github.com/bschueller/microprofile-demo-wildfly)

Comment: Are you launching WildFly with the `standalone-microprofile.xml`? Or have you added the appropriate MicroProfile subsystems?

Comment: I am launching wildfly with following parameter:
--server-config=standalone-microprofile.xml

Comment: Sorry you said that right in the question and I completely missed it :) Do you by chance have a reproducer? This seems like it could potentially be a bug.

Comment: I don't think microprofile-config is in `org.eclipse.microprofile:microprofile`, you may need to depend on `org.eclipse.microprofile.config:microprofile-config-api`. Also please add *exact* error message.

Comment: @dualed If you have a look in the maven repository, you see that microprofile-config-api is a dependency from microprofile. => https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.microprofile/microprofile/3.3

Comment: On server you do not see any exception. Just the AUTH-Header is missing after the call from one rest-service to another. I only saw an CNF-Exception in DefaultClientHeadersFactoryImpl.config() while debugging.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins The test projects are here: https://github.com/bschueller/microprofile-demo-wildfly

Comment: Oof, apparently I was remembering that wrong... Well, I only used Quarkus with MicroProfile, this seems WildFly specific now...